# dynamically name the div in html and access the same using @ViewChild('xyz') div: ElementRef; in angular

Tags: angular

I wanted to create a div inside *ngfor and assign a dynamic id to it and access it in component using viewchild and elementRef my current html is as below

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let consult of crap | keyvalue; let j = index; trackBy: trackByFn;">
     <td>
       <input  type="radio" name="radio-{{i}}" id="radio-{{i}}-{{j}}(click)="questBuild(consult)"/>
             <label class="sr-text" for="radio-{{i}}-{{j}}">{{consult.value.text}}</label>
               <ng-container *ngIf="consult.value.quest">
                  <div #questions></div>
                </ng-container>
          </td>
    </ng-container>
```

and accessing it in component as

```
  @ViewChild('questions') div: ElementRef;
```

f
so is there a way to name #questions dyncamically inside *ngFor and access it using @viewchild in component

Answer (score 0):

use [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren). View Children is a QueryList where you has all the elements.

```
@ViewChildren('question') questions:QueryList<ElementRef> 
//or is yer "questions" are components
@ViewChildren('question') questions:QueryList<ComponentName>
```

You can access to a particular element as

```
const question=this.questions.find((x,i)=>i==index)
```